# Laravel and PHPUnit: TestCase in Laravel Package not found

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am currently developing a small package and wanted to add tests for it but somehow the Class `TestCase` of my package is not found.

Here is the error Message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Tjventurini\GetRelationshipKey\Tests\TestCase' not found in /home/vagrant/code/get-relationship-key.local/packages/get-relationship-key/tests/BelongsToUserTest.php:5
```

Here is my composer file:

```
{
    "name": "tjventurini/get-relationship-key",
    "description": "Trait and sample configuration to manage model relationships via configurations.",
    "type": "package",
    "keywords": [
        "tjventurini",
        "laravel",
        "eloquent",
        "get-relationship-key"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Thomas Venturini",
            "email": "me@example.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "illuminate/support": "^6.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tjventurini\\GetRelationshipKey\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tjventurini\\GetRelationshipKey\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of my file structure:

[image]

The Test that throws the error:

```php
<?php

namespace Tjventurini\GetRelationshipKey\Tests;

class BelongsToUserTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * Test the BelongsTo relationship on the test model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBelongsToUser(): void
    {
    }
}
```

And finally, the class that causes problems ...

```
<?php

namespace Tjventurini\GetRelationshipKey\Tests;

use Tests\CreatesApplication;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;

    /**
     * Setup the test suite.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->setupConfiguration();
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    private function setupConfiguration()
    {
        config('database.models', ['foo' => 'bar']);
        dd(config('database'));
    }
}
```

It would be awesome if someone could tell me what I am missing here. Thank you!

Comment: Did you run `composer dump-autoload` in your package directory?

Comment: Why should i run this in my package directory? It should work with the same autoloading than the rest of the laravel project. I tried it out anyway but with no luck ...

Comment: You'll have to import the `TestCase` class like so: `use Tests\TestCase;`. Check these [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/testing#creating-and-running-tests) for further information.

Comment: I don't want to use the TestCase class from laravel, but rather my own. And since it lays in the same directory as the class extending it, I don't have to declare a use statement for it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found out, that the `autoload-dev` attribute in my `composer.josn` file just applies to the root package. Meaning that it is not applied when creating the autoload files.

To solve the issue I just moved the test namespace into my normal `autoload` list and it works.

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tjventurini\\GetRelationshipKey\\Tests\\": "tests/",
            "Tjventurini\\GetRelationshipKey\\": "src/"
        }
    }
```

Simple, but it works!